# synonyms in oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle

i have synonym like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE SYNONYM "DBTWO"."CATEGORIESSNNM_DB1TODB2" FOR "CATEGORIES"@"DBLINK";
```

Here I am accessing categories table from other db by creating a dblink named dblink.

but whenever I tried to execute the query

`desc dbtwo.categoriessnnm_db1todb2`
through java I am getting below issue

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement.
```

Here , I have two questions :

1.Is the issue because of dblink ?

2.can we create a synonym for multiple tables - means

```
create  synonym  synonym_name  for  table1,table2...;
```

Any answer would help me a lot!

Comment: Please don't spam tags. What does this question have to do with JavaScript or Python?

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Is the issue because of dblink ?

`DESC` is an Oracle SQL*Plus command. It is not a valid SQL command, hence the error message you get.

> 2.can we create a synonym for multiple tables

A synonym identifies one object, usually as a way of disguising complexity (such as a schema name or db link). There is no way to share one synonym across multiple objects. Besides, why would we even want to do that?